# Find and Replace text between ^ and ~ in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a large text file where I want to remove all text between the ^ symbol and the ~ symbol. This needs to work across lines as well.

I tried doing a regular Find and Replace using `^*~` in the Find box and nothing in the Replace box but it found 0 results.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is not possible with a regular *Find and Replace*. If you use Notepad++ 6, you can take advantage of the new regex engine that supports [PCRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) ([source](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-6.0-release.html)).

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to open the *Find and Replace* dialog and perform the following action:

```
Find what:          \^.*?~
Replace with:       
Wrap around:        checked
Regular expression: selected
. matches newline:  checked
```

Now press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to replace all occurrences.

The regular expression in *Find what* is composed as follows:

- `\^` is a literal **^**.
- `.*?` is the least amount of characters that allows the regular expression to match.
- `~` is a literal **~**.

Comment: if you change .*?~ to [^~]*~ then it should work without requiring / using PCRE.

Comment: @barlop: I took *regular Find and Replace* as *Search Mode: Normal*, not *Find and Replace* using regular expressions. That might have been a misunderstanding. In any case, if I remember correctly, versions prior to 6 did not support multi-line patterns.

Comment: The `.*?` pattern worked for me to search between characters of `;` and `<`.  So the search is FIND `;.*?<` REPLACE `;` with the options selected for `Regular expression` and `. matches new line`

Answer (score 8):

You're gonna want to search for `\^.*?~` and make sure **. matches newline** is enabled:

[image]

This is because `^` has a special meaning, it matches the beginning of a line. Thus, we need to escape it with a backslash `\^`.

Writing `^*` would match "any number of start-of-line in a row". `.*` matches "any character", but by default it doesn't match newlines.

Comment: Be careful with the regex's greedy behavior.  If there are multiple `~` characters (or ie. multiple matches) this will match the first `^` all the way to the last `~`.

Comment: @heavyd  <question>Are you sure?</question>.  He has used `*?` that is not greedy it's lazy   `.*?~` will never match more than one `~`. So it's ok.

Comment: @barlop: He commented shortly after I answered. It was a ninja-edit.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this regex in the find section `\^[^~]*~`  to replace everything between ^ and ~ inclusively.

Comment: and for exclusively, then I suppose that requires PCRE, then do something     (?<=^)[^~]*(?=~)   I don't have n++ to test it, butif that fails try changing (?<=^) to (?<=\^)

Comment: For exclusively, just replace with `^~`.

Comment: @Dennis I mean if he wants to replace everything between the ^ and ~ but not including the ^ and ~

Comment: Isn't that what you get if you replace `\^[^~]*~` with `^~`?

Comment: @Dennis oh I see what you mean, good point.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar BETWEEN replacement requirement with start and end characters. 
 This came from outlook email; hundereds of members and I just wanted the person names with everything removed between `<`**RemoveTextHere**`>`.

**Original**

```
First1 Last1 <First1.Last1@email.com>; First2 Last2 <First2.Last2@email.com>; First3 Last3 <First3.Last3@email.com>; First4 Last4 <First4.Last4@email.com>;
```

Dennis was close to my solution `Find what: \^.*?~` but I had to change my literal characters `Find what: \<.*?>` then I had to remove the first slash `Find what: <.*?>`.

**Updated** `Find what: <.*?>`; Replace empty.

```
First1 Last1 ; First2 Last2 ; First3 Last3 ; First4 Last4
```

_

**Special Characters**: `*`, `$`, `\`, `+`, `^`, `(` and `)`, `[`, `]`, `{` and `}`

Special Characters are described by Jerry Jeremiah here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37742519/notepad-wildcard .

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.