# Bookmarking specific lines in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I've got a list of links on notepad++, each line is a link.

for example:

```
http://support.volvocars.com/my/pages/default.aspx

http://www.volvocars.com/us/cars/new-models/s60

http://mcafee.org/root/Support.aspx
```

How to only bookmark url's without a host name or sub-domain?

Meaning how to only bookmark url's like this: `http://mcafee.org/root/Support.aspx`?

Tried TONS of stuff and I could not figure this out...
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "mark" them how?  Exactly what "tons of stuff" did you try already, and what were the results (to avoid us offering something you've already tried)?

Comment: marking them using shift+F, at the mark tab, tried replacing the dots of the links with a different character like "=" used and searched for this: http://.*?.*?=.*?.*?=.*?.*?/ with regular expression. at first it seems to work, but it also selects the links that I'm trying to mark. also tried doing this: http://superuser.com/questions/554387/find-and-replace-text-between-and-in-notepad but I can't seems to get it to find anything.

Comment: Ahh gotcha on the marking. "Top-level" actually refers to the ".com" part.  You want urls with only a (single) domain name + top-level; not ones with a host name, or sub-domain(s) -- which is tricky for sure.  I updated your question to reflect that; if you disagree with my changes, feel free to roll them back. :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit and corrections, didn't manage to make the post look tidy with the site's post editor. anyway hope someone could find an answer to this.

Comment: I tried a few things, but it stumped me for now.  Hopefully someone better at RegEx will come along and be able to figure out how to pull this off for ya. :)

Comment: I still don't really understand your question, please explain (by editing your post) what's allowed for you and what's too long.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following regex.

> http://\w+.(org|com)

Here is the GIF that shows how it works. Hope it helps.

(**Note:** I did not have many test cases (3), so you may have to build on it)

[image]

Comment: +1 only because of efforts you put in to teach someone visually !!