# Excluding regex match criteria from replacement

Tags: regex

I'm new to regex and I'm trying to do something [similar to this](https://superuser.com/questions/554387/find-and-replace-text-between-and-in-notepad) with regex and the replace feature in Notepad++

I want to replace all text between `:/` and `(123` where `123` can be any numbers but I want to exclude the search criteria itself from the replacement - currently it's selected.

So far I have this regex:

```
:/.*? \([1-9][0-9][0-9]
```

which finds the appropriate strings to replace but still includes the search terms as replaceable.

Comment: In your subsequent pedantic edit, Jake Gould, you screwed up the expression I had for the regex. But don't worry about it - I'll just find the information I require somewhere  (anywhere) else.

Comment: Please, give some input strings and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
:\/(.*)\(\d+
```

In <kbd>Notepad++</kbd>, you can then do Search and Replace with `\1`